# how do I ignore rest of character using equals?

Tags: android

Just straight to example:

```
String data1 = "1A";

if(data1 .equals("1"))
{
//do A
}
else
{
//do B
}
```

If I run this, it will do B progress. How can I make it to do A progress?

Comment: Do you need to compare whole `data1` or just a substring of `data1`?

Comment: This question is of low quality, and answered too many times..

Comment: @PankajKumar I know it's simple question but I tried to search and I didn't got anything, maybe I search it wrong, I don't know. Should I delete this?

Comment: No... wait, if other members will think same, they will close it. By deleting this question you will still some points of the guy who answered you, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String data1 = "1A";

if(data1 .startsWith("1"))
{
//do A
}
else
{
//do B
}
```

Comment: Although this answer is correct, who downvoted???????

Comment: I don't know why this got downvote but I tried this and it works, thanks

Comment: @downvoter - please tell me why

Comment: yaa...its right answer why downvoted ?? i think it shoud be +1

Comment: upvotes would be nice.

Comment: accept will be better :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String data = "11A";
String searchString = "11";

    if (data.substring(0, searchString.length()).equals(searchString)) {
        //do A
        System.out.println("a");
    } else {
        // do B 
        System.out.println("b");
    }
```